# How to align items?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

How I can write this:

[image]

I tried `\begin{align}` but I can't write in it

```
$$
\limsup_{|t|\to 0}\dfrac{}{}...
$$
```

I also tried `\begin{itemize}` but the same thing I can't write something in the center.

Comment: but how to align (1) (2) and (3) ?

Comment: that is an `enumerate` list just use `\begin{enumerate} \item There are... \item there exists... \item The function ... \end{enumerate}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle IMHO it is rather an `enumerate`

Comment: @Denis thanks just in time I could still edit:-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all: [*don't do this!*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) LaTeX and MathJax are strangers, not friends!

---

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}[(A)]
\item Hello World
\item \begin{enumerate}[(1)]
    \item This is some math
    \[1+2=3\qquad4+5=6\]
    \item This is another item
    \item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\item Something more
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what it means \lipsum[1]

Comment: It is a placeholder for some blind text, i.e. getting some text displayed to show what it looks like, without having to type it out.

Comment: @PolineSandra It is the first paragraph of the famous document named "Lipsum".

Comment: Why we put it ?

Comment: @PolineSandra I put it to see what real-document text should look like. In your document, remove it and add your own paragraph. Read more [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: ok thank you I want to write $ H_1 $ in a straight way how to do please ?

Comment: @PolineSandra Change `[(A)]` to `[(H1)]`.